# How can I get my ListView to focus in on a particular item?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, collections

I can't seem to figure it out, because I don't seem to be able to cast my ListView's items to the ListViewItem type and call ListViewItem.Focus(). The following won't work because the ListView's items are of type LogRecord:

```
((ListViewItem)listView.Items[0]).Focus();
```

EDIT: I want the scrollbar to move to where the item is, basically, or better said, that the item becomes visible in the list of items the user sees.

Any ideas on how I can get my ListView to focus in on a particular item? Right now its bound to a collection. Here's how I set up my ListView object:

```
listView = new ListView();
Grid.SetRow(listView, 1);
grid.Children.Add(listView);
GridView myGridView = new GridView();
// Skipping some code here to set up the GridView columns and such.
listView.View = myGridView;
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = PaneDataContext.LogsWrapper;
listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

I bind to this data type (LogRecord contains things like LogRecord.Message that corresponds to a Message column on the grid view, etc.; and the code works):

```
        public class LogRecordWrapper : IEnumerable<LogRecord>, INotifyCollectionChanged
        {
            public List<LogRecord> RowList { get; set; }

            public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

            public LogRecordWrapper()
            {
                RowList = new List<LogRecord>();
            }

            protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (CollectionChanged != null)
                {
                    CollectionChanged(this, e);
                }
            }

            public void SignalReset()
            {
                OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, null));
            }

            public void Add(LogRecord item)
            {
                RowList.Add(item);
                OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
            }

            public IEnumerator<LogRecord> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return RowList.GetEnumerator();
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
```

Comment: ListView.ScrollIntoView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview.aspx

Comment: @Blam - Thanks so much. Saved my life. Please, post this solution as an answer so that I may accept it.

Comment: @Blam - What if the ScrollView is not currently part of a focused element? This seems to not actually do this operation unless the scroll view is part of an element that is focused. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView.ScrollIntoView

[ListBox.ScrollIntoView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview.aspx)

The link says ListBox but it works with ListView also

As for not working with Focus please post how you are using ScrollIntoView.

Comment: I'm using Telerik's RadPane controls. Its a docking tool like how you have docking and panes in Visual Studio. I add my listView to the RadPane, and ScrollIntoView will work on RadPanes that are visible, but it will not work on RadPanes that are tabbed, strangely enough.

Comment: I know for sure its calling the method with the correct item, but when the RadPane is tabbed and not visible or pinned and not visible, it just won't scroll that into view...

Comment: I found a way to get around it by setting the pane up with a boolean that represents if it needs to synchronize to a certain record and then hooked up to the active pane change event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use:

```
listView.Items[0].Focused = true;
```

...or perhaps:

```
listVIew.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

(I'm not positive what kind of "focus" you are after)

Then combine with (or use in place):

```
listView.Items[0].EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: I want the scrollbar to move to where the item is, basically, or better said, that the item becomes visible in the list of items the user sees.

Comment: But... listView.Items[0] does not have Focused or Selected or EnsureVisible because they're not of type ListViewItem, because of the data binding to my collection of LogRecord's.

Comment: My initial problem is this case of data binding to a collection that is not of type ListViewItem, so now how do I ensure an item is visible?

Answer (score 1):

This is amazing!!!!
05-29-2002, 04:53 PM #1 Jim Guest 
ListView EnsureVisible not working. Any ideas? 
 The code ... in fact find and highlight selected item, it’s just not scrolling
 to it and making it visible. The user is forced to scroll to the item.

04-04-2004, 12:07 AM  luchmun
Hi,
working on a form...Everything goes fine but the problem is that even i use the lstitem.ensurevisible with listitem.selected = true the current entry does not become visible.

11 YEARS later and still it does not work and no one, not even Microsoft seem to know why?
The answer that works for me is listview1.ensurevisible(itemindex) NOT listview.items(itemindex).ensurevisible